# Can a Spring FactoryBean get access to all of the properties in the context?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to write a Spring FactoryBean that will produce a list of Request objects. The number of requests and the values that go into them are configurable at runtime, so I want to use properties for these.

Each request comprises of a pair of ID values, so I need some way of providing the Factory Bean with a configurable list of these ID pairs (Call them A and B for now).

What I've got so far is to use a property that looks something like:

```
requests=1/2,3/4,5/6
```

which then defines three requests, one with A=1 and B=2, one with A=3 and B=4, and one with A=5 and B=6.

This is obviously a bit nasty to configure, and rather prone to errors. What would be much nicer would be to do something with the values split out over many properties, so the above could be something like:

```
requests.1.A=1
requests.1.B=2

requests.2.A=3
requests.2.B=4

requests.3.A=5
requests.3.B=6
```

Which just makes it a bit more obvious what is going on.

However, I can't find any way of having my FactoryBean configured to access *all* of the available properties, instead of just the specifically named property that is passed in from the context.

Am I missing something here? Or - even better - is there a better way of doing this kind of config that is easier supported and maintained?

Comment: Why invent your own? Spring can use a properties file (next to xml or java) to create beans, the [`PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader.html). Just use that, create a file, load it and well be done.

Comment: I did not know that even existed. However, it's customer configuration and not us, and there's other config they need to provide as well, but I'll have a play and see if it works :)

Comment: So and why would that matter? In your factory bean load the configuration, get all the beans from the `BeanFactory` and presto. Judging from the post you are determining the configuration format. As long as you specify it you can use whatever you want. Where the file is located doesn't matter either if you can create a `Resource` it will work. And with it you can set all properties (or constructor arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject an [Environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) bean into your FactoryBean instance, it is provided by the context and you do not have to configure it. I am not sure how you are configuring your beans, but I always favor Java config. So this example will use Java config.

```
@Configuration
class FactoryBeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public FactoryBean(final Environment env) {
        return new MyFactoryBean(env);
    }
}
```

The Environment instance will give you access to all the properties, because it is a [PropertyResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html) You can programmatically loop over the properties

```
int x = 1;
while(true) {
    env.getRequiredProperty("requests." + x + ".A")
    env.getRequiredProperty("requests." + x + ".B")
}
```

Comment: Ooh - I didn't know you could inject the Environment like that. That looks very hopeful :) I'm using XML configuration, but I presume it just works the same way?

Comment: If you want the environment just add a field of type `Environment` and put `@Autowired` on it. You don't need to inject it like this...

Comment: @M.Deinum you are correct. It's just how I like doing it. But there are a couple of way to get the Environment injected

Comment: I would simply add `@Autowired` on the constructor of the factory bean (assuming it is annotated with `@Component`), saves you writing a configuration class.

Comment: It's a personal thing, I think creating Configuration classes are more explicit. If the OP has a code sample if his configuration I could give him an example in his own style of configuration

Comment: For those of us using XML config, there's an EnvironmentAware interface to get hold of it too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that to create instances of a specific bean I would suggest using a [`PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader.html). Specify 2 property files to load (one well known to configure the defaults) and one to add beans.

*core-request.properties*

```
request.(class)=com.company.pkg.Request
```

*requests.properties*

```
requests1.A=1
requests1.B=2

requests2.A=3
requests2.B=4

requests3.A=5
requests3.B=6
```

Now you can use your `FactoryBean` to construct a `BeanFactory` and obtain all the beans and expose them as a list.

```
public class YourFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<List<Request>> {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader rl;

    public Object getObject() {
        DefaultListableBeanFactory beanRegistry = new DefaultListableBeanFactory;
        PropertiesBeanDefinitionLoader loader = new PropertiesBeanDefinitionLoader(beanRegistry);
        Resource core = rl.getResource(core-location);
        Resource requests = rl.getResource(requests-location);
        loader.loadBeanDefinitions(core);
        loader.setDefaultParentBean("request");
        loader.loadBeanDefinitions(requests);
        return beanRegistry.getBeansOfType(Request.class).values();
    }

}
```

Something like that.